# TensorFlow: Why is there a need to reshape non-sparse elements once when parsing a TF-example from TFRecord files?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

In the TensorFlow documentation at [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/data/tfexample_decoder.py), there is this following code:

```
# Reshape non-sparse elements just once:
for k in self._keys_to_features:
  v = self._keys_to_features[k]
  if isinstance(v, parsing_ops.FixedLenFeature):
    example[k] = array_ops.reshape(example[k], v.shape)
```

I am wondering why there is a need to reshape a FixedLenFeature tensor after parsing it from a TFRecord file.

In fact, what is the difference between a FixedLenFeature and VarLenFeature and what is their relevance to a Tensor? I am loading images in this case, so why would all of them be classified as a FixedLenFeature? What is an example of a VarLenFeature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensors are stored on disk without shape information in an [Example protocol buffer format](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto) (TFRecord files are collections of Examples). The documentation in the `.proto` file describes things fairly well, but the basic point is that Tensor entries are stored in row-major order with no shape information, so that must be provided when the Tensors are read. Note that the situation is similar for storing Tensors in memory: the shape information is kept separately, and just reshaping a Tensor changes only metadata (things like transpose, on the other hand, can be expensive).

VarLenFeatures are sequences such as sentences which would be difficult to batch together as regular Tensors, since the resulting shape would be ragged. The [parse_example documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/converting#parse_example) has some good examples. Images are fixed length in that, if you load a batch of them, they'll all have the same shape (e.g. they're all 32x32 pixels, so a batch of 10 can have shape 10x32x32).

Comment: Meaning to say is it alright that when I created my TFRecord files, it is alright that my images all don't have the same shape, because before I load them into the batch I would have reshaped them already? Is it correct to say that for images we can't use VarLenFeatures as it would give us a sparse tensor (that is not suitable for images)?

Comment: The problem is when it comes to batching the images. You're free to read variable-length arrays from disk, but the only efficient way to train an image model is to get them into a dense, batched format, which means resizing all of them. So reading sparse tensors, resizing them, making them dense, then batching them would be a perfectly fine input pipeline.

Comment: Is it right to say that if I had resized all my images to the same size (e.g. 500x500), even if I have to resize them into a smaller size (e.g. 299x299) later on by preprocessing, it is more efficient to read these images because I would be stating the content as FixedLenFeature as I read the TF-examples? Also, since the TF-examples are read in one by one, how is FixedLenFeature distinguishable from VarLenFeature if the machine has no knowledge of the shapes of other examples it had previously read (this is just an assumption)?

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether the resizing/reshaping happens in TensorFlow or not performance-wise, assuming there's enough parallel processing and IO is not a bottleneck. The advantage of doing it in TensorFlow is that you can then easily switch things around, and since it's more of an end-to-end pipeline it's likely more repeatable. On the second question, the input reader doesn't know whether your input is fixed length or not, it just knows whether the number of elements matches the integer you passed to FixedLenFeature.